# Duplicate pages in djvu without significant file size grow

Tags: creation, djvu

I have a multipage djvu document with several pages which in fact are same. These are usually pages "for notes" at the end of document. Or empty pages without content between chapters. They are all identical.
Are there a way to include only one copy of such page in djvu document and display it whenever user try to view one of these identical pages?
I would like to minimize resulting djvu filesize.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the pages (e.g. with `djvm`), to see how much that would bring? Empty pages are stored quite efficiently and even text pages that are the same should compress to very little (assuming a good DjVu generator) for each extra copy.

Comment: You are right. I've tested it with 10 copies of "For Notes" page that contains only a few lines and djvu increased by ~5kb only. And I searched through the  djvu format reference and didn't found any mentions of required functionality. So it seems doesn't worth it.